# Transform an object of objects to an array (special example)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to transform an object of objects into an array of objects.  Basically I want to transform this:

```js
    sales_over_time_week: {
          "1": {
            "orders": 96,
            "total": 270240
          },
          "2": {
            "orders": 31,
            "total": 74121
          }
        }
```

into this:

```js
[
    {name: 1, orders:96, total:270240}, 
    {name:2, orders:31, total: 74121}
]
```

To just transform it normally I would do this

```js
     var myData = Object.keys(items).map(key => {
        return items[key];
      });
```

and it would give me

```js
[
    {1: {orders: 31, total: 74121}},
    {2: {orders: 52, total: 180284}}
]
```

but my example is a bit special

Comment: btw, the canonical solution of the first part is to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` with `.map()`

```js
let data = {
      "1": {
        "orders": 96,
        "total": 270240
      },
      "2": {
        "orders": 31,
        "total": 74121
      }
    };
    
 let result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({name: key, ...value}));
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: worked, thank you very much :) choosing it as an answer in some mins

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Object.keys(data).map(k=> ({name:+k, ...data[k]}));
```

```js
data = {
      "1": {
        "orders": 96,
        "total": 270240
      },
      "2": {
        "orders": 31,
        "total": 74121
      }
    }
    
let r = Object.keys(data).map(k=> ({name:+k, ...data[k]}));

console.log(r);
```